# Error while creating rpm package using rpmbuild from spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to build a rpm package from a spec file(hello-world.spec).The command and error output are given below
Command1:

```
rpmbuild -ba hello-world.spec
```

ErrorOutput1:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.z4GoQn
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ 
: not foundm-tmp.z4GoQn: 28: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.z4GoQn: 
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.z4GoQn (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.z4GoQn (%prep)
```

Content of my spec file is

```
Name:       hello-world
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    Most simple RPM package
License:    FIXME

%description
This is my first RPM package, which does nothing.

%prep
# we have no source, so nothing here

%build
cat > hello-world.sh <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo Hello world
EOF

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/
install -m 755 hello-world.sh %{buildroot}/usr/bin/hello-world.sh

%files
/usr/bin/hello-world.sh

%changelog
# let's skip this for now
```

My System/software details are

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- RPM version:4.12.0.1

The list of contents in rpmbuild folder is

---

Command2:

```
:~/rpmbuild# ls
```

Output2:

```
BUILD  BUILDROOT  RPMS  SOURCES  SPECS  SRPMS
```

Can anybody help on this issue?

Comment: Does `-bp` also fail? I'm guessing Rpmbuild expects a SOURCES file or i doesn't prep properly.

Comment: hi ,it is giving different error.``` Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IWyuKo
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ 
: not foundm-tmp.IWyuKo: 28: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IWyuKo: 
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IWyuKo (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IWyuKo (%prep)
```

Comment: does your `/var/tmp` directory exist?

Comment: Yes.The `/var/tmp` directory exists.

Comment: The output of the command `ls -l` in the `/var/tmp` is as shown below 
`-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:33 rpm-tmp.fpbKle
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:40 rpm-tmp.HuT9DR
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:34 rpm-tmp.IWyuKo
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:33 rpm-tmp.k28tdE
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 01:23 rpm-tmp.q5rjJ9
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:41 rpm-tmp.Vp7pUC
-rw------- 1 root root  773 Dec 31 00:43 rpm-tmp.YLKilh
`

Comment: you spec file looks ok, this works fine on my machine (opensuse15.0, rpm 4.14.1). On what os, with what version of `rpm` do you work?

Comment: Hi ,My System OS in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It's a stupid question, but are you root ? Have you used `sudo su` and than `rpmbuild -ba hello-world.spec`. I've built it on CentOS and it works.

Comment: Hi Dinko, I know it looks stupid to you. But the issue i faced is real.If you know answer please provide.

Answer (score 0):

Check how your files is being generated. If you are passing files from windows to Linux, usually, there are different EOL for the files. We had a similar issue, I recommend you to change all the files to Unix format. I'm sharing with you how to reproduce your issue, if you edit that file in a Linux environment, like "nano", the problem disappears.

[image: EOL error]